# Is there a quick way of zeroing a struct in C#?

Tags: c#, struct

This must have been answered already, but I can't find an answer:

Is there a quick and provided way of zeroing a `struct` in C#, or do I have to provide `someMagicalMethod` myself?

Just to be clear, I know the struct will be initialised to 0, I want to know if there's a quick way of resetting the values to 0.

I.e.,

```
struct ChocolateBar {
    int length;
    int girth;
}

static void Main(string[] args) {
    ChocolateBar myLunch = new ChocolateBar();
    myLunch.length = 100;
    myLunch.girth  = 10;

    // Eating frenzy...
    // ChocolateBar.someMagicalMethod(myLunch);

    // myLunch.length = 0U;
    // myLunch.girth = 0U;
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve here, but `length` and `girth` will be 0 by default, all integers are 0 by default.

Comment: I know, but I've set them and I want them reset to 0.

Comment: `default(T)` is the all zero struct. For structs written in C# `new T()` is equivalent to `default(T)`

Comment: @Liam - haha touché mate.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the equivalent of Delphi "ZeroMemory" in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5350132/what-is-the-equivalent-of-delphi-zeromemory-in-c)

Comment: If you're restting all the values, why not just create a new one? ( myLunch = new ChocolateBar(); )

Comment: @Liam - I laughed when I seen 'girth' too, must be a Liverpool thing. OP - .net doesn't know about 'reset' in this context. You'll have to create a new struct, or set the values manually.

Comment: Incidentally... I originally called the struct `Banana`, but it pained me to quantify it...

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Just use:

```
myLunch = new ChocolateBar();
```

or

```
myLunch = default(ChocolateBar);
```

or

```
myLunch = default;
```

These are equivalent<sup>1</sup>, and will both end up assigning a new "all fields set to zero" value to `myLunch`.

Also, ideally don't use mutable structs to start with - I typically prefer to create a struct which is immutable, but which has methods which return a *new* value with a particular field set differently, e.g.

```
ChocolateBar myLunch = new ChocolateBar().WithLength(100).WithGirth(10);
```

... and of course provide appropriate constructors as well:

```
ChocolateBar myLunch = new ChocolarBar(100, 10);
```

---

<sup>1</sup> At least for structs declared in C#. Value types *can* have custom parameterless constructors in IL, but it's relatively hard to predict the circumstances in which the C# compiler will call that rather than just use the default "zero" value.

Answer (score 13):

Just call the parameterless constructor in your code:

```
ChocolateBar chocolateBar = new ChocolateBar();
```

Comment: Even better - this can be done _inside the struct itself_ (i.e. set `this`).

Answer (score 6):

A new `ChocolateBar` is initialized to zero. so:

```
myLunch = new ChocolateBar();
```

This only works because `ChocolateBar`is a struct/value type. If `ChocolateBar` were a class, this would create a new `ChocolateBar` and change `myLunch` to point to it. The values of the `ChocolateBar` stored in `myLunch` would be zero. The old ChocolateBar would be unchanged, and eventually be claimed by the garbage collector, unless some other reference pointed to the old myLunch too.

Answer (score 2):

`struct`s are a `value type`. They are set to zero by default when you initialize it.

`int` default value is zero. You don't have any need to set it to zero.

Answer (score 0):

Just add `Zero` into your struct, as shown below. Also, as a side point, consider using *constructors* in your structs, so that you can parameterize your variables instead of setting them individually:

```
public struct ChocolateBar {
    int length;
    int girth;

    public static ChocolateBar Zero { get; }

    public ChocolateBar(int length, int girth) {
        this.length = length;
        this.girth = girth;
    }
}

class OtherClass() {
    ChocolateBar cB = new ChocolateBar(5, 7);
    cB = ChocolateBar.Zero();

    Console.Writeline( (cB.length).ToString() ); // Should display 0, not 5
    Console.Writeline( (cB.girth).ToString() ); // Should display 0, not 7
}
```

The reason why `Zero` gets the 0 values, is because the default (static) values of `int length` and `int girth` are 0, as mentioned by others above. And `Zero` is itself static, so you can access it directly without an object reference.

In other words, most (if not all) your structs should have a `Zero` property, as well as a *constructor*. It's super useful.

Comment: Althought this statement: "cB = ChocolateBar.Zero();" should be "cB = ChocolateBar.Zero;" since Zero is a getter property.

Answer (score 0):

You can modify your struct in this way:

```
struct ChocolateBar {
    int length;
    int girth;
    public void Clear()
    {
        this = new ChocolateBar();
    }
}
```

and use it in your code easily:

```
ChocolateBar cb = new ChocolateBar();
//some stuff here
cb.Clear();
```